# Solving $\frac{dy}{dx} = ay^2 + (b + qe^{rx})y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been attempting to solve this differential equation:
$\frac{dy}{dx} = ay^2 + (b + qe^{rx})y$

I attempt solving the Bernoulli equation using $v = y^{-1}$.  However when I do this, I get an unsolvable integrating factor $e^{bx+qe^{rx}}$ that prevents me from solving this differential equation.

Is there another way to go about this problem that I may be overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Bernoulli type ODE:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}-(b+qe^{rx})y=ay^2 \implies y^{-2}\frac{dy}{dx}-(b+q e^{rx})y^{-1}=a.$$
Let $y^{-1}=v \implies -y^{-2}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dx}$, then we get, the linear ODE
$$\frac{dv}{dx}+(b+qe^{rx})v=-a$$
whose integrating factor is $I=\exp[bx+(q/r)e^{rx})]$
so the solution is
$$v=y^{-1}=\exp[-(bx+(q/r)e^{rx})] \int  -a \exp[bx+(q/r)e^{rx})] dx+ C \exp[-(bx+(q/r)e^{rx})]$$

Comment: So would the integral of the integrating factor not be solvable in this particular case?  ( The ∫−exp[+(/))] part of this solution) [AFTER EDIT]: ahh got it so the final solution would be $v = (−\frac{ar}{bq}^{−}+)*exp[−(+(/)^{})]$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I beg to differ. Only for special values of b,q,r it would be do-able. For instance $Exp[x+e^x]dx=Exp[e^x],∫Exp[2x+e^x]dx=Exp[e^x](e^x−1) $etc.

Comment: Therefore it wouldn't be solvable for all possible constants b,q,r is what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, it seems so.